# How can I prevent the users to press two button at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

In every activity in my app, the users are able to press two button at the same time.
How can I prevent they to do this?

Comment: post ur code, what u did actually...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you can disable the multi touch in the screen...which can allow only
>   single touch by
>
> place this line button viewGroup layout

**android:splitMotionEvents="false"**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonX).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
                    for (View touchable : group.getTouchables()) {
                            if (touchable != view && touchable.isPressed()) {
                                    Log.d("...", "skip");
                            }
                    }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable all other buttons on click listener of all buttons

Comment: does you means when user types 'a' then other alphabet disable...not a good logic..as much as i think

Comment: this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

On First button click, you can do this for particular seconds by running one thread

```
  second_btn.setEnabled(false); or second_btn.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are one near other you can make a radiogroup that do your job without any work:D. If not you can use a synk boolean variable and play witt all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

A radio group should do the magic. As the user will be able to select any one option(i mean the button at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this for every single button:

```
boolean buttonClicked = false;

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
       if(!buttonClicked) {
         buttonClicked = true;
         ...
         ...
         ...
         buttonClicked = false;
       }             
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable press two button at the same time multi-touch on your app by using this approach in your theme - it works fine!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
</style>
```